# Как подсчитать долю каждого элемента к определенному числу?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, проценты

Застрял на задачке, как подсчитать красиво долю каждого элемента к определенному числу.

Имеется DataFrame:

```
                               2017     %_2017      2018       %_2018   2019       %_2019
LONG-TERM ASSETS               779,179      0.00    1,004,790   28.95   1,163,862   15.83
CURRENT ASSETS                 23,540,367   0.00    39,743,268  68.83   47,939,841  20.62
CAPITAL AND RESERVES           1,917,017    0.00    2,650,657   38.27   3,520,344   32.81
Borrowed funds (long-term)       401,343    0.00    828,342     106.39  2,115,672   155.41
Borrowed funds (short-term)    1,828,969    0.00    2,241,601   22.56   962,358     -57.07
Total LIABILITIES              24,320,474   0.00    40,747,718  67.54   49,600,194  21.73
Revenue                        83,126,293   0.00    125,638,096 51.14   154,129,923 22.68
Operating profit (loss)         2,044,700   0.00    2,398,963   17.33   4,630,956   93.04
Interest expense                   72,849   0.00    60,733      -16.63    128,529   111.63
Pre-tax profit (loss)            2,120,085  0.00    2,912,776   37.39   4,992,523   71.40
Net profit(loss)                 1,710,746  0.00    2,454,176   43.46   4,267,316   73.88
```

Хочу добавить колонку к каждому году доля процентов, чтобы все строки которые выше `Total LIABILITIES` рассчитывались как долю строки к `Total LIABILITIES` (пример: `CURRENT ASSETS / Total LIABILITIES` и т.д.).

А все, что ниже `Revenue` считались как доли строки к `Revenue` (пример: `Net profit(loss) / Revenue`).

Пытался разделить на 2 DataFrame (все что выше `Total LIABILITIES` и все что ниже `Revenue`) и провести вычисления с применением `apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[-1]` и затем склеить оба DataFrame в один с помощью `concat`, но при вычислении выдает ошибку.

В итоге надо, чтобы получился следующий DataFrame:

```
                                   2017     %_sh_2017 %_2017   2018     %_sh_2018  %_2018          
LONG-TERM ASSETS               779,179        3.20    0.00    1,004,790     2.46    28.95       
CURRENT ASSETS                 23,540,367     96.79   0.00   39,743,268     97.53   68.83   
CAPITAL AND RESERVES           1,917,017      7.88    0.00    2,650,657      6.50   38.27   
Borrowed funds (long-term)       401,343      ...     0.00      828,342      ...   106.39   
Borrowed funds (short-term)    1,828,969      ...     0.00    2,241,601      ...    22.56   
Total LIABILITIES              24,320,474     100     0.00   40,747,718      100    67.54   
Revenue                        83,126,293     100     0.00  125,638,096      100    51.14   
Operating profit (loss)         2,044,700     2.45    0.00    2,398,963      1.90   17.33   
Interest expense                   72,849      ...    0.00       60,733       ...  -16.63     
Pre-tax profit (loss)            2,120,085     2.55   0.00    2,912,776       2.31  37.39   
Net profit(loss)                 1,710,746     ...    0.00    2,454,176        ...  43.46
```

Comment: в вашем реальном DF - строки вместо чисел или это вы для нас его так оформили с запятыми? ;)

Comment: Нет у меня нормально в датафреме, это я просто style применил при выводе в датафреме

Comment: у меня просто такой вид в style оформленmain_table.head(12).style.format({"2017": "{:20,.0f}", 
                          "%_2017": "{:20,.2f}", 
                          "2018": "{:20,.0f}", 
                          "%_2018": "{:20,.2f}",
                            "2019": "{:20,.0f}", 
                          "%_2019": "{:20,.2f}"})\
                    .applymap(lambda x: f"color:{'red' if x<0 else 'black'}")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
idx1 = "Total LIABILITIES"
idx2 = "Revenue"

d1 = df.iloc[:(df.index == idx1).argmax()]
d2 = df.iloc[(df.index == idx2).argmax() + 1:]

cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r"^\d+")]

r1 = d1[cols] / df.loc[idx1, cols] * 100
r2 = d2[cols] / df.loc[idx2, cols] * 100

res = (pd
       .concat(
        [r1.append(pd.Series([100] * len(cols), index=cols, name=idx1)),
         r2.append(pd.Series([100] * len(cols), index=cols, name=idx2))])
       .add_prefix("%_sh_"))
res = pd.concat([df, res], axis=1)
new_order = pd.Series(res.columns.str.replace(r"\D", ""), index=res.columns).sort_values().index
res = res[new_order]
```

---

результат:

```
In [111]: res
Out[111]:
                                 2017  %_2017   %_sh_2017       2018  %_2018   %_sh_2018       2019  %_2019  \
LONG-TERM ASSETS               779179     0.0    3.203799    1004790   28.95    2.465880    1163862   15.83
CURRENT ASSETS               23540367     0.0   96.792386   39743268   68.83   97.534954   47939841   20.62
CAPITAL AND RESERVES          1917017     0.0    7.882318    2650657   38.27    6.505044    3520344   32.81
Borrowed funds (long-term)     401343     0.0    1.650227     828342  106.39    2.032855    2115672  155.41
Borrowed funds (short-term)   1828969     0.0    7.520285    2241601   22.56    5.501169     962358  -57.07
Total LIABILITIES            24320474     0.0  100.000000   40747718   67.54  100.000000   49600194   21.73
Revenue                      83126293     0.0  100.000000  125638096   51.14  100.000000  154129923   22.68
Operating profit (loss)       2044700     0.0    2.459751    2398963   17.33    1.909423    4630956   93.04
Interest expense                72849     0.0    0.087637      60733  -16.63    0.048340     128529  111.63
Pre-tax profit (loss)         2120085     0.0    2.550439    2912776   37.39    2.318386    4992523   71.40
Net profit(loss)              1710746     0.0    2.058008    2454176   43.46    1.953369    4267316   73.88

                              %_sh_2019
LONG-TERM ASSETS               2.346487
CURRENT ASSETS                96.652527
CAPITAL AND RESERVES           7.097440
Borrowed funds (long-term)     4.265451
Borrowed funds (short-term)    1.940230
Total LIABILITIES            100.000000
Revenue                      100.000000
Operating profit (loss)        3.004579
Interest expense               0.083390
Pre-tax profit (loss)          3.239165
Net profit(loss)               2.768649
```

---

PS если хотите разобраться как работает данное решение, то советую выполнять каждую строку отдельно и смотреть на промежуточные результаты. Также длинные команды, разделенные точками можно выполнять постепенно - сначала выполняем первую часть комманды (до первой точки), на следующем шаге добавляем следующую команду и т.д.

Comment: большое спасибо, разобрался! Работает все здорово!